# Import/ install Pandas and Matplotlib on Azure Function

Tags: python, pandas, azure, matplotlib, azure-functions

I'm trying to import python libraries to Azure Function, But when I run the code locally and on the server, I get a message that these libraries are not available!
"No module named 'pandas' ",   No module named 'pandas'., ...etc
I added them to the requirements.txt file and I'm still getting the same error

**The Output**

> Executed 'Functions.PandasTest' (Failed,
> Id=298034b9-f97d-4610-850a-c5fd67d5bccb, Duration=3ms)
> [2022-07-21T10:34:59.0052] System.Private.Corelib: Exception while
> executing function: Functions.PandasTest. System.Private.Corelib:
> Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'pandas'. Troubleshooting Guide:
> https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python
> 3.9\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 315, in _handle_function_load_request

**requirements.txt**

```
azure-functions
nltk
numpy
pandas
six
```

**init.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    import pandas

    mydataset = {'cars': ["BMW", "Volvo", "Ford"], 'passings': [3, 7, 2] }

    myvar = pandas.DataFrame(mydataset)

    #Retreive Method type, it tells us what kind of request we're receiving
    method_type = req.method

    if method_type == "GET":
        name = req.params.get('name') #getting the name argument from a get request from req "func.HttpRequest" :- we check if this request contains a 'name' argument in it
    
    elif method_type == "POST":
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()  #check if the request contains json "if we recieve a json", if this code execute without any errors, we go to the else statement, if there is any exceptions in this line we go to except ValueError:
        except ValueError:
            name = None
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')  #get the name value

    if name:  #we check if the name was found
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.", status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Pass a name in the query string (GET request) or a JSON body (POST request)",
             status_code=400
        )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deployment of azure function in python doesnt install dependencies from requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704759/deployment-of-azure-function-in-python-doesnt-install-dependencies-from-requirem)

Comment: [Azure Functions Python developer guide - Folder structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level#folder-structure)

Comment: [Troubleshoot ModuleNotFoundError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#troubleshoot-modulenotfounderror)

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue,

After seeing your error logs, it seems that you have not configured properly pandas in your environment (i.e in local).

Once you have created your Azure function and trying to use pandas for your requirement . As suggested by @ *DeepDave-MT* in comment this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501043/15969165) try to run the command ;

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It will show the `requirement.txt` file of your project and then add `pandas` *and all your reuqired SDKs which will need to use for your environment* .

Then save and run the cmd:- `pip install -r requirements.txt`  *then test your function it should work*.

***REFERENCE SNAPSHOT:-***
[image]
[image]

[image]
*For more information please this* **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Install required Python Azure SDK libraries***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-serverless-cloud-etl-04#1-install-required-python-azure-sdk-libraries)

Comment: Thanks Ajay! but I've done this before, and I've done it again now. But I still have the same problem: Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'.

Comment: Could you  please try to restart the IDE once ,

Comment: I did, unfortunately, the same issue

Comment: Could you please try to create a new project.

Comment: Please share your requirement.txt file and the `.py` code details in your question.

Comment: I created a new project and I did everything again from scratch, but unfortunately I'm still facing the same problem!

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246652/discussion-between-ajaykumarghose-mt-and-proved-jo).